# Magento 2.3.1: Customer account edit page translation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

How i can translate to another language?

If you created this account using Amazon Pay, you might not know your site password. (link)Request a password to change your account password.(link)

[image]

This doesn't work: `"If you created this account using Amazon Pay, you might not know your site password. <a href=""%s"">Request a password to change your account password.</a>"`

Answer (score 1):

content coming from `vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml`

So, you have to disable amazon pay module

```
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Payment
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Login
php bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is still current and for everyone who came across this post while searching.

In magento 2.3 it seems that this string is split into two parts.

"If you created this account using Amazon Pay, you might not know your site password."

and

"Request a password to change your account password."

Translating these two separately worked for me. Also, you don't need the variable for the password link. It was enough to translate only the string as written above.

Comment: What I couldn't find, however, is the original file from which these strings come.

Maybe someone is so smart and can come up with this information. Can't hurt.